# I am trying to test my application in window 8 but device is not visible in android device chooser

Tags: android, usb, device-driver

I am trying to test my application but some of my devices are not visible  android device chooser.
Amazon kindle fire , **nexus 7** and other Android carbon devices are not visible,
some devices (Samsung Galaxy tab2 ) are working properly. 
When I am checking the device manager it shows a message like... 
"The drivers for this device are not installed"
so help me from getting this out.

Devices is showing in other devices category with yellow marked sign.

I reinstalled driver many times.

Comment: Did you turn on USB Debugging on device ??

Comment: yes i did..
Device are visible on other environment like linux and mac.. @joao2fast4u

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Google USB Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html). If you are using Nexus device, it is required. You can find it in android SDK manager.